# How do I do computations on a user inputed list of numbers in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to know how to do computations on a user inputed list of numbers. Here's my code so far, I'm lost as to how to proceed. I need to write a code that asks whether or not the user wants to manually input numbers or upload from a file. If user chooses manual, I have to find the average, min, max, and stand. dev. of the numbers they input. Any help would be appreciated

```
    import java.io.*;

public class computation {
//main method starts
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        //create text input reader
        InputStreamReader get = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader got = new BufferedReader(get);
        //create a text printer
        PrintWriter send = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);

        //defining a string type variable for user input
        String answer1;
        //asks the user if they want to input data from keyboard
        String question = "Do you want to input data manually? Enter y or n";
        send.println(question);
        //system reads user input
        answer1 = got.readLine();

        if (answer1.equals("y")) {
            send.println("Enter numbers separated by spaces");
            String datacurrent = got.readLine();
        } //end of "y" if
        if (answer1.equals("n")) {
            send.println("Enter the path of your data file");
        } //end of "n" if


    } //end of main method
} //end of class computation
```

Comment: `" I need to write a code that asks whether or not the user wants to manually input numbers or upload from a file. If user chooses manual, I have to find the average, min, max, and stand. dev. of the numbers they input. Any help would be appreciated` -- any first attempt by you would be appreciated as well. Please at least try.

Comment: This seems like a homework question, generally frowned-upon here.

Comment: Homework is OK, but they have to *at least* show an attempt. Else how will we know what to help them with. We're not a substitute for tutorials/books and efforts to first learn the language. Original poster, please respond before your question gets closed.

Comment: I did make attempts, by trying to convert the input string of numbers into doubles and then making them into arrays but I jsut kept getting system errors from my IDE (Eclipse). I didn't realize I posted my code before after I made the ommissions of my errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your program, it seems alright.

**(A)** What to do when values inputted through console ?

Split the string into an array, extract each number and then calculate **Average**, **Min**, **Max**, and **Stand deviation**.

**For ex:**

```
String[] numbers = datacurrent.split(",");

for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++)
{
....
}
```

**(B)** What to do when inputted as file path ?

You will have to read the file using `File Stream/Buffer Reader`.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Your string variable pointing to path));
```

And then loop through file data.

**Note:** You need to know the text file format in order to loop through the file content.

Comment: Yes what I needed was to split the string into arrays by cutting out the commas! Thank you, that was all I really needed I know how to do the rest now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the newer class `System.console` that we got that faciliates easier console i/o. Your program shows attempt and if you study one or two good Java books you will beable to write this program error-free. Two good new Java books are the Sierra / Bates OCJP study guide and the new [A Press Java 7 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430247649). I recommend you take a read or two from one or two of these books and you will learn how to use ? System.console for console i/o.

```
System.out.print("Enter something:");
String input = System.console().readLine();
```